# switching finite sum and finite integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is it always allowed to switch finite integrals and finite sums?
for example,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \int_B f_n(x) dx = \int_B  \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) dx
$$
is this always valid assuming each $f_n$ is continuous and $B$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I think I have taken this for granted... How does one prove this? thank you!

Comment: You prove finite sum-integral exchange by induction over the linearity of the integral, which should have been one of the first things you looked at. No assumption on $B$ or $f_n$ is required beyond the normal ones - that they are measurable sets and the $f_n$ are integrable functions

Comment: If $E$ is a measurable set and $\{f_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$, with $f_k\ge 0$, is a sequence of measurable functions then $$\int_E\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_E f_k \right).$$ In general if $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ is measurable and $f_k:E\to \overline{\mathbb R}$ are measurable functions in $E$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_E |f_k|<+\infty\implies$ $$\exists g:E\to \overline{\mathbb R}\text{ measurable in }E: \sum_kf_k(x)=g(x)\in\mathbb R\text{ a.e. in} E\\ g\in L(E)\\ \int_E g=\sum_k\left(\int_E f_k \right).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's allowed in your case since the functions $f_n$ are integrable on $B$ since they are bounded on $B$ and $B$ has finite measure. In general, linearity of integration $\int (f + g) = \int f + \int g$ holds when each function is integrable, or when each function takes values in $[0, \infty]$. The proof involves details of the construction of the integral. Essentially, you prove it directly for simple functions, and then extend it to nonnegative measurable functions using the monotone convergence theorem. See any measure theory or probability theory book, e.g. Klenke's book for details.